# Facebook profile link with app id

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I know can access some person profile picture with your app id of that user like this:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/USER_APP_ID/picture?type=large
```

But, can i get a link to that user profile from my app?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you see and tried my answer..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From new api you need to pass the access_token to access the user's details. Without access_token you will not allowed to fetch any single detail from graph api.

So pass your application's accessToken as a parameter in graph url.

e.g

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USER_APP_ID/picture?type=large&access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

**NOTE:**

Use HTTPS in URL while using access_token field in graph api.

Answer (score 0):

The link would be: `https://www.facebook.com/USER_APP_ID`

It should redirect to the real profile, you can´t get direct access to the real one.

Answer (score 0):

To access a user profile from you app you can use:

```
http://facebook.com/USER_APP_ID
```